# Simplify this problem from Spivak's Calculis.

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I'm sorry I don't have the book with me (don't know the problem number) since I moved, but I still remember the problem.

It said something about finding $\int x^n\ dx$ by letting $p_n = \int_0^1 x^n\ dx$ and finding a general formula for $p_n$.

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2a} x^n\ dx
&= 2a\int_0^1 (2ax)^n\ dx\\
&= (2a)^{n+1} p_n
\end{align}$$

Additionally

$$\begin{align}
(2a)^{n+1} p_n
&= \int_0^{2a} x^n\ dx\\
&= \int_{-a}^a (x+a)^n\ dx\\
&= \int_{-a}^a \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k a^{n-k}\ dx\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^{n-k} \int_{-a}^a x^k\ dx\\
&= \sum_{k\text{ even}}^n {n \choose k} a^{n-k} 2\int_0^a x^k\ dx\\
&= \sum_{k\text{ even}}^n {n \choose k} 2a^{n-k} \cdot a^{k+1} p_k\\
&= 2a^{n+1} \sum_{k\text{ even}}^n {n \choose k} p_k\\
2^n p_n &= \sum_{k\text{ even}}^n {n \choose k} p_k
\end{align}$$

But this is where I'm stuck. I went through values of $n$ to confirm $p_n = p_0/(n+1)$ where $p_0 = 1$. But I haven't been able to prove this using induction (with step size of $1$ or $2$) or any other tricks I know. I thought I'd try rewriting the above to

$$\sum_{k\text{ even}}^n {n \choose k} (p_k-2p_n) = 0$$

But that doesn't help either. The problem always seems to boil down to not being able to simplify $\sum a\cdot b$.

Comment: Is the question to prove $p_n = p_0/(n+1)$ or the relationship between the integral for $0$ to $2a$ and the one from $0$ to $1$, or is it required to establish the derivative (and hence anti-derivative) of $x^n$ from first principles?

Comment: perhaps it would help if you could be more specific about where you are going with this. "proving $\int x^n dx$" is meaningless as $\int x^n dx$ is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I'm trying to prove $p_n = p_0/(n+1)$

Comment: Do you need to establish a formula for $\frac{d}{dx}x^n$ from the definition of the derivative, or is it okay to use the power rule without derivation?

Comment: @Marconius I'm trying to find a general formula for $p_n$ directly from the last equation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $2^n = (1+1)^n =\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}$ and $0 = (1-1)^n =\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}(-1)^k$, which combine to give you $\sum\limits_{k \text{ even}}^n {n \choose k} = 2^{n-1}$, and therefore $\sum\limits_{k \text{ odd}}^n {n \choose k} = 2^{n-1}$. This latter expression can be rewritten as $2^n = \sum\limits_{k \text{ even}}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose k+1} = \sum\limits_{k \text{ even}}^{n+1} {n \choose k}\frac{n+1}{k+1}$. Or: $$2^n\frac{1}{n+1} = \sum\limits_{k \text{ even}}^{n+1} {n \choose k}\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Comment: Sorry I don't see how to use this. :\

Comment: Never mind, got it. Thanks!

Comment: Good. It's always better to spot something yourself.